# multithreading and reading from one file (perl)

Tags: multithreading, perl, file, fork

Hej sharp minds!

I need your expert guidance in making some choices.

Situation is like this:
1. I have approx. 500 flat files containing from 100 to 50000 records that have to be processed.
2. Each record in the files mentioned above has to be replaced using value from the separate huge file (2-15Gb) containing 100-200 million entries.

So I thought to make the processing using multicores - one file per thread/fork.

Is that a good idea? Since each thread needs to read from same huge file? It's a bit of a problem loading it into memory do to the size? Using file::tie is an option, but is that working with threads/forks?

Need your advise how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: Are the records all the same size? If not, will the record change size when you edit it?

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the big file will be searched for corresponding entries.

Comment: the records from the big file will be truncated in some cases (depending on information in small files)

Comment: After re-reading the question, the real problem is needing a way to locate the appropriate information in the large file rapidly. You'll need to create some kind of index. Looking towards a database system, even something as simple as a BerkleyDB, isn't a bad idea.

Comment: what about loading file into a hash (memory is not an issue) and then use it as shared resource for threads? would that help?

Comment: Sure, if the hash fits in memory, there's no reason to use a disk based hash (which is all BerkleyDB is, really), whether threads are used or not. I doubt you'll get much value out of threads, though, and it might actually slow things down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course, using multiple cores for multi-threaded application is a good idea, because that's what those cores are for. Though it sounds like your problem involves heavy I/O, so, it might be that you will not use that much of CPU anyway.

Also since you are only going to read that big file, `tie` should work perfectly. I haven't heard of problems with that. But if you are going to search that big file for each record in your smaller files, then I guess it would take you a long time despite of the number of threads you use. If data from big file can be indexed based on some key, then I would advice to put it in some NoSQL databse and access it from your program. That would probably speed up your task even more than using multiple threads/cores.

Comment: If you're right that he's not using that much CPU anyway, then I don't see how you can say that multithreading will help.

Comment: I presume you mean Tie::File, which will take a lot MORE memory than without. Furthermore, it's not likely that you can share it between threads, so all that extra memory will be per-thread!

Comment: Can the array holding Tie::File by shared between threads using thread::shared?

Comment: I thought about indexing... perhaps even make things in binary mode, but that most likely will be my separate question...